# How to insert values into a table according to the index values of columns in MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sql-insert

I want to add values according to index in my table.

This is the code I am trying right now.

```
insert into A(1,2) values ('ABC','CBA');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `insert` statement does not accepts column *indexes*, but column *names*. Say your table called `a` has three columns called `id`, `col1` and `col2`, and you want to insert into the last two columns, you would do:

```
insert into a (col1, col2) values('ABC', 'CBA');
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way that you can add columns according to *position* is to leave out the column list and include *all* columns:

```
insert into A
     values ('ABC', 'CBA');
```

That said, you really should be explicit about which columns are getting values, by including the column names:

```
insert into A (col1, col2)
     values ('ABC', 'CBA');
```

Or using the MySQL `set` extension:

```
insert into A (col1, col2)
     set col1 = 'ABC', col2 = 'CBA';
```